# running the strace command just halts the terminal

Tags: linux, strace

Why STRACE shows resource is unavaliable even when I fired the  resource?
Is there any way to find the strace of all processes running in the system?
Some times if I run the strace command it just hangs the terminal.
Can you guide me in the right direction?

Command:

```
sudo strace -p 1803
```

Output:

```
read(3, 0x7f8d07c94074, 4096) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI},     {fd=15, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}, {fd=40, events=POLLIN}, {fd=22, events=POLLIN}], 8, 3997) = 1 ([{fd=22, revents=POLLIN}])
read(22, "\372", 1) = 1
```

Comment: Try with `-f`. It will trace child processes and threads